# Plotting multiple lines on plotly

Tags: r, plot, plotly

**head(betas)**

```
           historical_beta implied_beta
2015-11-05       0.4876163    0.4558767
2015-11-06       0.4828677    0.4856059
2015-11-09       0.4628628    0.4369807
2015-11-10       0.4636145    0.4492920
2015-11-11       0.4511203    0.4558034
2015-11-12       0.4418248    0.4175937
```

Now I have to plot both timeseries on the same graph.
I know

```
plot_ly(y=betas$historical_beta)
```

but how to add multiple y-axis?

Answer (score 3):

Does this do what you want?

```
df1 = stack(betas)
plot_ly(df1,y=values,group=ind)
p
```

or

```
p <- plot_ly(betas,y=historical_beta)
p <- add_trace(p,y=implied_beta)
p
```

or in case you really meant 2 y axes:

```
ay <- list(
  tickfont = list(color = "red"),
  overlaying = "y",
  side = "right"
)
p <- plot_ly(betas,y=historical_beta,name="Historical Beta") %>%
       add_trace(y=implied_beta,name="Implied Beta",yaxis="y2") %>%
       layout(yaxis2=ay)
p
```

The first one does a nicer job of automatically labeling the traces.